# My stored procedure not returning all rows of my table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a script to update my database.

My problem is that my stored procedure of the first table does not return all rows just 1000  and in my database there's 848301.

This my stored procedure :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetAllProducts;
    SELECT * FROM csii;
    DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts ()
BEGIN
         DECLARE csii_id INT;
         DECLARE csii_fk_cc INT;
         DECLARE csii_s VARCHAR(255);
         DECLARE csi_p DECIMAL;
         DECLARE csi_c_a DATE;
         DECLARE csi_o_p DECIMAL;
         DECLARE csi_shi_c DECIMAL;
         DECLARE csi_xc_s VARCHAR(20);
         DECLARE csi_wei VARCHAR(20);
         DECLARE csi_fk_c_at INT;
         DECLARE csi_sta enum('a','i','d');

         SELECT 
            id, fk_cc, s, p, c_a, o_p, shi_c, xc_s, wei, fk_c_at, sta
         INTO 
            csii_id, csii_fk_cc, csii_s, csi_p, csi_c_a, csi_o_p, csi_shi_c,
             csi_xc_s, csi_wei, csi_fk_c_at, csi_sta
     FROM 
            csii
     WHERE 
            csi_sta = sta AND csi_sta = 'a';

     SELECT  
            csii_id, csii_fk_cc, csii_s, csi_p, csi_c_a, csi_o_p, csi_shi_c,
             csi_xc_s, csi_wei, csi_fk_c_at, csi_sta;
END|
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are you running the proc in?  MySQL workbench has a 1,000 row limit in results - which is oddly the same as you are seeing.  Are you sure it is your proc?

Comment: seems like you have an environment limit set, how are you testing your results?

Comment: I test on MySQL workbench,I did not know the limits is 1000. yes this is my stored procedure.

Comment: when I use a temporary table for the same request in Mysql Workbench it gives me the same result 848301

Comment: I remove the limit clause from MySQL Workbench, it turns no stop and when i limited in 50000 or 90000 it works more than that it crashed.